# How to push new code to a *nix web server?

Tags: svn, ssh, webserver

I am new to web servers and I would like to know what the best method is to push new code from a development machine to production server running in the cloud.

I don't think downloading and unzipping zipfiles to the web host is the best way to update code.  I think SVN can do this too, but is it the method to follow or there is a better one?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the target environment you are normally trying to minimize the number of things that may break on the way, and based on this consideration two natural leaders would be:

- "scp -p tarball.tar.gz /path_to & tar xzf tarball.tar.gz"
- "rsync -ac /path_from to:/path_to"

both with subsequent md5 check

Answer (score 0):

I think this question might be better off on serverfault, but anyway.

1. svn checkout on the webserver - cron or trigger to update
2. rsync to copy to the webserver from a local checkout.
3. Automate (ssh keys etc), copy tarfile to webserver.